# Out of memory exception - perm gen space when creating rest template

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am creating a rest template `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate()`. But I am getting this error out of memory exception during the creation.
When I debug the rest template creation, the error exactly is occuring at `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConvertor`
It is a multi threaded environment, still only one thread is creating the template, rest other threads are doing some other process.

Comment: OOM error is not about thread(stack) memory but about heap memory. looks like you have too many objects in memory - make heap dump to analyze what exactly fills all the memory. as a solution you may need to increase heap size via jvm parameter: `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: Thank you add this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOM error is not about thread(stack) memory but about heap memory.

It looks like you have too many objects in memory - make a heap dump to analyze what exactly fills all the memory: 
[useful link about capturing heap dumps](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-capture-java-heap-dumps-7-options)

After an analysis of your specific case, as a solution (if it's okay to have such amount of objects in the memory) you may need to increase heap size via jvm parameter: -XX:MaxPermSize=512m